# Image compression - Speed and Latency

Tags: image, latency

Which is the best way to reduce size fast and decompress it fast?

I will be using it for, real time video (sharing desktop).
And i don´t think a video compression will do any good there.

Speed and Latency is everything here, i am currently looking at LZ4 for compressing a bmp, as it´s pretty fast, but it starts to be quite the bottleneck at higher resolutions (1280x720), and i only mean in compression and decoding speed, not in CPU usage.

I prefer lossless, but if there is a lossy (transparent?) option i am willing to try it out of course.

EDIT:

I am looking at libjpeg-turbo, but i have no idea how to use it in c#, can´t seem to find any information on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Red5 Media server? It's an open source software to stream videos.

Comment: I want to use my own application for a bit of reasons. Thanks for the suggestion though:)